# How to set training parameters in Random decision forest for classification?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, random-forest

I am using Random Decision Forest for face recognition.I have database of 51 people. For each person I have used 34 images for training the classifier and 17 images for testing. Size of my feature vector is 11340.

I have done programming in c++ using opencv V2.4.9.

Few declarations are..

```
# define NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_SAMPLES 1734

# define ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE 11340

# define NUMBER_OF_TESTING_SAMPLES 867

# define NUMBER_OF_CLASSES 51
```

While setting parameters to train Random Decision Forest I have set those parameters as..

```
CvRTParams params = CvRTParams(50,15,0,false,10,priors,false, 0,510,0.01f,
                       CV_TERMCRIT_ITER |   CV_TERMCRIT_EPS);
```

I want know how to set 2nd (min sample count) and 5th(max number of categories) parameter.

I have read on opencv tutorial that for min sample count resonable value is small percentage(e.g. 1%) of the total data. I didn't get what does mean by total data.